# Viewing large Oracle RDBMS ERD with table and keys only

Tags: oracle

I am new to Oracle, I have been asked to reverse engineer a huge legacy database; so huge in fact that when I went to view the ERD, it took up 3 plot diagrams; 3 walls.

I cannot zoom in; it is because there are numerous attribites (hundreds per ...)

Is there a way to:
1) View just table names, keys and relationships
2) Restrict the scope of the table names, keys and relationships

Is there a tool that would be present in large Enterprises that the DBA could grant me read permission to perform this analysis.

Thanks for your assistance!!! Chris

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you Oracle SQL Developer Data Modeler

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/datamodeler/overview/index.html

Where you can :

- Create subViews from whole ERD model

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E25259_01/doc.31/e25257/data_modeling.htm#BABCIAEG

- Display only names (without attributes)
- It is used for Big Enterprise data analysis projects
- Many useful features

> And the best feature : It´s FREE